# How do I attach an action to a button using Interface Builder?

Tags: ios4, interface-builder

I am new to Interface Builder.  I have a method (IBAction) defined in my class.  I want to fire this method when a particular button is clicked.

I cant see any way to add an action via the IBBuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Setting up an Action

1. **Right-Click** on your **control instance**
2. **Drag** to your **target** and **let go**.

[image: Setting up an Action]

---

### Setting up an Outlet

1. **Right-Click** on your **object instance**
2. **Drag** to your **control instance** and **let go**.

[image: Setting up an Outlet]

---

### Inspecting Actions/Outlets/Bindings

1. **Right-Click** on your **object instance**

[image: Inspecting Actions/Outlets/Bindings]

Comment: Wow.  Well, I do see the line... but where do I drop it to?  I have a method declared in my .m file... dragging it to the XCode editor didnt work...

Comment: never mind, after moving that line all over the screen, the first responder box animated and I think I have it.  Wow

Comment: @user605957: I added a screenshot as it says more than words. (Another trick: try right-clicking objects in IB for a list of actions/bindings).

Comment: Thanks.  How do I add a new referencing outlet?  That is, a UIBarButtonItem variable in my class?

Comment: I think I just drag in the opposite direction?

Comment: @user605957: Exactly ;) Anyway, I updated the screenshot for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined your method as an IBAction? You need to do like this for the method appear in the "File Owner's".